# Are there any linux distros that fit onto a 128MB USB drive and have a RDP client?

Tags: linux, usb, remote-desktop, usb-flash-drive

The subject kinda tells it all... I'm looking for a Linux distro that fits onto a 128MB flash drive, can boot from it, and run a Remote Desktop client that I use to connect to a Windows PC.

Is there something out there that fits the bill out-of-the-box, or do I have to make one myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/index.html) and [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/index.html) should both fit your bill.

Answer (score 2):

[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org) has an RDP client.  The [current ISO](http://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/puppylinux/puppy-4.3.1/pup-431.iso) is 108MB.

> You don't have to install Puppy (to hard disk) to use it. Simply burn the ISO to CD/DVD and boot the PC or laptop with it. Once booted, you can then install it to USB flash (see the Setup menu), so you can use it for booting the PC when a CD is not available.

Answer (score 2):

[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) is 50MB and contains rdesktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can build one, fitting your exact need, using [SUSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/).